# What exactly is causing this error whne compiling the node?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a simple node that responds with a message when an image from camera is received. I have specific node provided by the ROS for this camera to open it and other to request the data. Now i want to write a simple subscriber that is subscribed to the topic that is being published by the request data node and i want my node to simple acknowledge the image received with a simple message.

Here is the code for my simple node

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg){
     ROS_INFO("I heard the image");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node_vision");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("image_listener", 1000, imageCallback);

    ros::spin();
    

    return 0;
}
```

when trying to ros run this node, there is a syntax error with '(' token near the line where i am defining the imageCallback function. But to me all the syntax looks correct and hence I suspect there is something somewhere else going wrong with this node which then caused a domino effect ended up with this error. Can anyone please help me with this. Thank you.

Here is the error

```
/home/sganapa/catkin_ws/src/montage-anwendung/montage_roboter/src/ensenso_tutorial.cpp: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/sganapa/catkin_ws/src/montage-anwendung/montage_roboter/src/ensenso_tutorial.cpp: line 10: `void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg){'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348164/what-exactly-is-causing-this-error-whne-compiling-the-node-?/) by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2020-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-02**:
No one will be able to help you unless you show the error message you received.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2020-04-02**:
Here I have added the error. As said, it says syntax error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-02**:
It's likely there are other errors before this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How did you run the the node? What is the exact command? This error seems like you were trying to execute a cpp file instead of  the binary compiled by `catkin`. I guess you probably ran your node like this

```
rosrun package_name ensenso_tutorial.cpp
```

Replace `ensenso_tutorial.cpp` with your executable target in `CMakeLists.txt`

---

Originally posted by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) with karma: 241 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2020-04-02**:
yea exactly that was the error. Thank you.